# Why are my questions still flagged even after I tried to clarify them?

Tags: support

I have asked multiple questions which were either said to be unclear or and they silently got down voted/flagged. Examples are [Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53987364/how-can-use-a-string-variable-as-an-instance-name-of-a-gtk-widget) [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53239146/how-do-i-acess-a-gtkmm-widget-in-another-class) [Q3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53742072/how-can-i-show-only-the-second-number-in-a-string).

I would have put an example, gave details or tried to be specific. I do my best to explain my issue. Sometimes being specific is difficult since I wouldn't be having proper insight on why I am asking about. My efforts at trying to explain seem not to be enough.

Other users ask for clarity yet keep quiet with no feedback after I try to make things more clear. I tried to clarify my question and my question remains flagged.

Comment: sometimes users flag and then move on.. don't take it personally. if the question is closed and then edited and become more clear, other users probably will vote to reopen if it is relevant.

Comment: As ObmerkKronen points out many times we vote to close questions and we do not monitor them, but if they closed it then in the closing message appear the users who voted for what if you consider that your question has improved so that it considers reopening then you can notify the users using `@username`

Comment: Side note: if you have not finished chapter about arrays in language you are using it may be a bit too early to sk on SO... as consequence such knowledge is implied and you need to explain why you can’t use arrays for multiple similar objects.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov hmm I just saw what you said in a new light for my array question thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't have solid domain knowledge in any of the languages that you're asking about, so I can't personally speak for the clarity of the questions.

I will note though that a few established users have commented and said that your question is unclear. This suggests that before you ask, you may need to take step back and consider context, and make sure that people *entirely* unaware of your problem are given enough surrounding information to be able to answer. I should be able to read the first paragraph and have a *general* idea what you're asking about; usually via a clear problem statement (similar to a thesis statement).

---

What I *can* comment on is:

> when I do they keep quiet yet I tried to clarify my question and my question remains flagged

This is the problem when posting on a site like Stack Overflow that has *massive* traffic.

Here's my "workflow" when visiting Stack Overflow: I view my favorited tags to find new questions that I have particular domain knowledge in. If that fails to bring up anything interesting, I begin browsing the new question feed. This exposes me to a ton of questions that I can chose to focus my attention on. When looking at a question, I have to make a decision:

- Is this question worth focusing my attention on
- Or is it likely to be closed/abandoned by the OP and my efforts will be wasted

If there's even a hint of it being the latter, I'll likely decide to look for a better question that is "more worth my time", unless it's abnormally interesting.

Now look at your questions from our perspective. The question was slightly unclear from the start, and subsequent edits only partially clarified it. At some point, we need to cut our losses and move on to better questions; because we won't benefit from spending time on a question that is bound to be closed/forgotten about by the OP.

---

So, what am I trying to say? You need to make an extreme effort to ask a question here. Your question should quickly summarize your problem, give all the relevant information quickly, and be as short as possble, but as long as necessary. We shouldn't have to dig through your question to find what you're asking, or play 20-Questions to get to the bottom of your problem. When I ask a question here, I spend at least an hour writing the question and covering my bases (and that doesn't include prior debugging for debugging questions).

Make our lives as easy as possible, and we'll make your life as easy as possible. If we can't understand your question, we'll move on to another one that is more accessible.